# SINGLEVALUEQUERY and MULTIVALUEQUERY with Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: formula, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have multiple data sets that drive the Pentaho report.  The data is derived from a handful of stored procedures.  I need to access multiple data sources within the report without using sub reports and I believe the best solution is to create open formulas.  The SINGLEVALUEQUERY I believe will only return the first column or row.  I need to return multiple columns.

As an example here my stored procedure which is named HEADER in Pentaho (CALL Stored_procedure_test (2014, HEADER)), returns 3 values - HEADER_1, HEADER_2, HEADER_3.  I'm uncertain of the correct syntax to return all three values for the open formula.  Below is what I tried but was unsuccessful.

```
=MULTIVALUEQUERY("HEADER";?;?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter denotes the column that contains the result.

If you dont give a column name here, the reporting engine will simply take the first column of the result. In the case of the MULTIVALUEQUERY function, the various values of the result set are then aggregated into a array of values that is suitable to be passed into a multi-select parameter or to be used in a IN clause in a SQL data-factory.

For more details see https://www.on-reporting.com/blog/using-queries-in-formulas-in-pentaho/